# Remove white background from the image and make it transparent using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick

I got this code to do that:

```
$im = new Imagick("test.jpg");
$im->paintTransparentImage($im->getImageBackgroundColor(), 0, 500);
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->writeImage('finish.png');
```

And this is the result (I added manually pink background to see the problems  better):

[image]

When I increase the `fuzz` then more white pixels disappear next to the object but then more white pixels also disappear inside the object.

I tried the same image on a website and the result there is:

[image]

Which is pretty perfect. Does someone know how to do that?

In case someone need the original image for testing:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Adding `$im->despeckleimage();` before `$im->paintTransparentImage` makes a better result:

[image]

The only thing needs to be done is fill fill the small empty areas with white pixels. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The second solution is the worst it just removes every white pixel and the third isn't PHP. Can someone tell me the solution with PHP?

Comment: First soluton also only removes the 100% white pixels, why did you even answer

Comment: i am sorry my bad.

Comment: @AnneSchwarz what html did you use to get the third solution? Can you edit your question and add it in? Also what code did you add to increase the fuzz? Could you elaborate your question with a bit more relevant code?

Comment: "what html did you use to get the third solution?" what? oO fuzz is set to 500 in the code

Comment: Starting with a jpeg image for this type of operation is a bad place to start. You should be using PNG images which your graphics department produce....if you're taking images from someone else's website, you're in for a bad time. However this might help:
http://phpimagick.com/Tutorial/backgroundMasking

Comment: it gives me error 500 :/

Comment: But i guess it's not good enough anway, the white pixels INSIDE object are getting removed too

Comment: You could try Active Contour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtained an instant solution using the **GrabCut Algorithm**. I used OpenCV 3 with python to get your desired output. Unfortunately I do not know `php` nor do I know `imagik`.

**CODE:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Dress.jpg',1)
cv2..imshow('Original image',img)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

rect = (60,20,325,503)

cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
nimg = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

cv2.imshow("Extracted image",nimg)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I first created a black background using the `mask` variable.

This is what I obtained.

[image]

Visit [THIS PAGE](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) for details of this algorithm and the parameters used. You can work this out for masking on a colored background also.

I beleive the same can be tried out with `imagik` also.  Hope this helps :)

**EDIT:**

This is in response to the edit you made to the question.

The following was the image uploaded by you:

[image]

I applied threshold and obtained the following image:

[image]

Now I performed 'morphological closing' operation and obtained this:

[image]

Finally I masked the image above with the original image you uploaded in the beginning to obtain this:

[image]

Comment: That looks very good. I'm gona check the algorithm used there and give feedback when I could use something from there. I just updated the question please check it out. Maybe you know a solution to fill the small empty areas with white pixels?

Comment: Yes got it. Convert your image to binary image (black & white), such that the pink color becomes black and the dress remains white. Now perform morphological closing operation. Done!!!

Comment: That looks very promissing but I got problems with the host right now, I'm gona perform that s soon as possible and give feedback :D

Comment: Ok I can try around again, is making the background black at beginning rly necessary? And can you tell me which values must be in: thresholdimage($threshold * \Imagick::getQuantum(), $channel); ?

Comment: You can add any color to the background. I chose black because it is contrasting to the white dress. The threshold value I chose for the python code was 127.

Comment: I finally solved it after installing one more extension and some configs. This algorithm is working :D Thanks