# Corner detection in Image processing Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I have an image of the box. I am trying to detect corners and mark those corner from circles. I am using the following code for this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_file = 'Image.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

imgDim = img.shape
dimA = imgDim[0]
dimB = imgDim[1]

# RGB to Gray scale conversion
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# Noise removal with iterative bilateral filter(removes noise while preserving edges)
noise_removal = cv2.bilateralFilter(img_gray,9,75,75)
# Thresholding the image
ret,thresh_image = cv2.threshold(noise_removal,220,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(noise_removal, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

# Applying Canny Edge detection
canny_image = cv2.Canny(th,250,255)
canny_image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(canny_image)

# dilation to strengthen the edges
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
# Creating the kernel for dilation
dilated_image = cv2.dilate(canny_image,kernel,iterations=1)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)

_, contours, h = cv2.findContours(dilated_image, 1, 2)
contours= sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:1]


corners    = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(thresh_image,6,0.06,25)
corners    = np.float32(corners)

for item in corners:
    x,y    = item[0]
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),10,255,-1)
cv2.namedWindow("Corners", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Corners",img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

This code will return my image with pointing edges with circles but you can see that two edges (edges at the back of the box) are detected incorrectly. I know there is some problem in determining the corners because here we are just plotting the corners. Can anyone guide me where I am doing it wrong ? Thanks [image]

[image]

Comment: after determining the edges, find out a way to find the intersections of these edges => CORNERS. :)

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say find out the intersection of edges ?

Comment: Obtain the Canny edge of the images and find their intersections. Visit [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-a-sudoku-square/11366549#11366549) .Hope it helps

Comment: Can you upload the original image ?

Comment: @JeruLuke original image added. Your reference was useful I am studying that post and trying to learn. Appreciate if you can guide a bit more.

Comment: ok before finding the corners of the box just try extracting the box and removing the background. [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526023/php-remove-white-background-from-the-image-and-make-it-transparent/41567320#41567320) will help you with that. I would have used the **GrabCut** algorithm. After extracting the box finding corners would a tad bit easy I guess!! :)

Comment: Also visit [THIS PAGE](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't say I have reached the best solution, but after quite a lot of coding I was able to obtain the following:

[image]

To obtain this I followed the following steps:

***1. First: Obtain the edges of the box***

- I performed **bilateral filtering** on the grayscale image.
- Found the edges using **Canny edge detection**.
- Enhanced the edges using **morphological dilation**.

This is the result of the above:

[image]

Now when I did **Corner detection**, I was not at all satisfied:

[image]

So what did I do?

***2. Finding desired corners***

- I **blurred** the dilated image using a window of size 9x9.
- Then applied **Harris corner detection** to this blurred image.

As a result I was able to obtain this:

[image]

I know it is not perfect but it can always be fine tuned.

Here is the code for corner detection:

```
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(dilate,2,3,0.04)
#----result is dilated for marking the corners, not important-------------
dst = cv2.dilate(dst,None) 
#----Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image---
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It was best solution for me so far.

Comment: I am really glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

@Jeru Luke. Why not Harriscornering based on the result data from your step1?

> 1. I performed bilateral filtering on the grayscale image.
> 2. Found the edges using Canny edge detection.
> 3. Enhanced the edges using morphological dilation.

If you do that the painting on the corners would be neat and fit within the lines, right?

Comment: after step 1 I had many false corners detected. See the image after the result after step 1