# Custom shape of an Image Android

Tags: android, image-processing

[image]

I want any image to take the shape of this black part. How will I be able to do this in android? I have many other designs like this.

Comment: you can set "transparent" color to the black part and match background color to the rest of the part, then overlap this to any image. You will get your desired result.

Comment: If you are using OpenCV  you can use `cv2.bitwise_and()`

Comment: Make sure that the image you are using and the custom image in question are of the same size...

Comment: use `PorterDuffXfermode` with `DST_IN` / `SRC_IN` mode

Comment: Thanks I'll check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this one.
https://github.com/mafujuls/mafs-image-shape

Integrate this lib:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.mafstech.libs:mafs-image-shape:1.0.4'   
}
```

After implementing, you just need to write a single line code with some parameter. That is:

`Shaper.shape(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.your_image, R.drawable.your_shaped_image, your_image_view, height, weight);`

For more detail: https://github.com/mafujuls/mafs-image-shape

Answer (score 0):

You can work this out using OpenCV for Android.

Resize the image you want to work with to the size of the custom image. Here is mine:

[image]

Then I inverted the custom image to :

[image]

I used the function `cv2.bitwise_and()` as in the following:

```
final = cv2.bitwise_and(resized,resized,mask = thresh)
cv2.imwrite('final.jpg',final)
```

and obtained this:

[image]

If you use the same custom image without inverting it, you will get this:

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks but I need the background to be transparent and only the shape should be filled

Comment: Ok, so to do that use the image above and follow [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526023/php-remove-white-background-from-the-image-and-make-it-transparent/41567320#41567320). I would have used the **GrabCut Algorithm**